# Inheritance of private inner class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, private

I want to implement Serializable into a class, but I am not allowed to modify it. My idea was to make another class which inherits from the other class. But the original class is built like this:

```
public class ClassName {

    private class InnerClass{
        private InnerClass(){
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public ClassName(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

So following does not work because `InnerClass` is private thus not visible:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ClassTwo extends ClassName implements Serializable{

    private class InnerClass extends ClassName.InnerClass implements Serializable {
        private InnerClass(){
            super();
        }
    }

    public ClassTwo(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement Serializable into `ClassName` without changing the original class?

Comment: If you have read/write access to all the slots you care to serialize, you can create a adapter class that contains a `ClassName`. If you don't have read/write access then subclassing wouldn't have worked anyway.

Comment: Slivio is basically correct, I think.  If you have access to getters and setters in `InnerClass` that let you rebuild an instance of the class, then you can do it with a wrapper of some sort.  If not, there's reflection.  Neither though are completely recommended. `private` means you shouldn't be able to inherit or access directly.

Comment: @Silvio I think you should write that comment as an answer. Nobody is going to see it in the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have read/write access to all the slots you care to serialize, you can create an adapter class.

```
public class MyClassAdapter implements Serializable {
    private MyClass instance;
    ...
}
```

Then just wrap the instance in this adapter class before serializing, and extract it after deserializing.

If you don't have read/write access to the slots, there's probably a good reason for that, and serializing data you don't own is a bad idea.